# Manifest on visual studio 2015 Community + Xamarin

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I started to learn Xamarin 2 days ago, but the capabilities looks diferent from any other tutorial I found.
And my code for WP8.1 doesn't work. 
The namespace `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` is not available.
Someone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are differences between the classes available within the Windows Phone world, and the Xamarin world. While they both share the same language (C#) and there are some crossover between libraries, there is not a 1:1 correlation.

If you are having troubles getting started, I highly suggest taking a look at the [Getting Started guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/). As you are a Visual Studio user, it may be more accurate to ensure that you are reading Visual Studio centric documentation. On pages where a difference may exist, there is a toggle on the upper right that will allow you to focus on Visual Studio. The toggle will look similar to [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwuki0lj6btqt84/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-24%20at%205.55.41%20PM.png?dl=0)

I hope this helps!